# How to use sparkmonitor extension on jupyterhub or jupyterlab 4?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Versions that I'm using:
sparkmonitor **4.1.0**
jupyterlab: **4.0.4**
spark: **3.4.1**

I've done all the steps suggested by https://github.com/itsjafer/jupyterlab-sparkmonitor#readme

The error is:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception when registering SparkListener

After some research, I've found what some say could be a version conflict, others state network, or firewall issues.

This is my config:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(f"JupyterNotebook-{user_name}")\
.config("spark.extraListeners", "sparkmonitor.listener.JupyterSparkMonitorListener")\
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sparkmonitor/listener.jar")\
.getOrCreate()
```

the listener.jar file exists in that directory, I've checked it.

just a reminder. I'm using jupyterhub that spawns containered jupyterlab images.